# Learning Curves that Seems to Overfit After the First Epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to interpret these learning curves.
These seem to overfit after the 1st epoch.
I have built a model using TensorFlow and the BERT transformer.

Is there another way to interpret these other than the optimum number of epochs is one?

[Accuracy learning curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uv7Fe.png)

[Loss learning curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcFu8.png)

Comment: It is definetly not training. Maybe you should lower your learning rate. Adding data augmentation would also help and applying regularization effects like dropout or l1, l2 regularizers. The available data is also important to be enough big for a NN to train

Comment: Yes your model is indeed overfitting after the first epoch. Have you tried playing around with the learning rate? It may have a big impact on the learning curve. Also, I assume you are working with a classification problem since you are using BERT. Did you make sure to choose the correct optimizers and the correct loss function ? is it cross entropy ?

Comment: Thank you both for responding. I am doing sentiment analysis with three labels, +ve, -ve, and neutral so yes, a classification task. 

I have played with the learning rate and it gives me 74% accuracy at the current setting 3e-5 which is the best after a few attempts. Surely this means that it IS training?

Total number of sentences is over 5000, financial phrase bank sentences.

The shape of them curves just doesn't change much regardless of learning rate or batch size.

Comment: And yes, im using cross-entropy and Adam